# Установить сессию в nodejs из стороннего сервиса

Tags: node.js, express-sessions

Основная задача состоит в том, что бы узнавать от какого пользователя приходят данные, возможно тот подход который я использую в данном примере не подойдёт.
Пытаюсь установить сессию для пользователя из одного сайта в другой, есть **site1** написанный на php и **site2** написанный на nodejs. C **site1** я отправляю ajax запрос на url http://site2:3000/send, там устанавливается сессия.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "http://site2:3000/send",
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: "http://site2:3000/test-send",
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Но как только я обращаюсь на следующий URL http://site2:3000/test-send той сессии которая ставилась для http://site2:3000/send больше нет. Код самого nodejs следующий

```
router.get('/send', function(req, res, next) {
req.session.test_req = "red";
console.log(req.session.test_req); // После обращения через site1 сессия в консоли есть
res.end();});

router.get('/test-send', function(req, res, next) {
console.log(req.session.test_req);  // После обращения через site1 сессии здесь уже нет
res.end();});
```

Если обращаться на **site2** напрямую через браузер, то сессии ставятся корректно и сохраняются.
Возможно ли решить задачу таким образом, что бы создать сессию для пользователя отправив ajax запрос через другой сервис или необходимо какое-то иное решение?

Comment: сессии нельзя передавать между ориджинами.

Comment: А каким образом можно узнать от какого пользователя был отправлен запрос?

Comment: В данном случае, проблема - на стороне браузера. Некоторые браузеры не принимают куки от сторонних сайтов (а ваш `site2:3000` с их точки зрения - сторонний сайт) с целью защиты пользователя от отслеживания.

Comment: Иными словами, браузеры намеренно мешают вам решать вашу задачу - "узнавать от какого пользователя приходят данные", и это не изменить.

Comment: Вы можете попробовать генерировать в /send токен, который далее будет проверяться в /test-send, но это потребует изменения клиентского кода. Либо придется возвращать не html, а json - либо надо будет добавлять обработку своих заголовков.

Comment: Получается если в send генерировать токен, то его необходимо будет положить в базу, а после возвращать, на клиент. А уже с клиента мы будем отправлять запрос на test-send (так же могут быть и другие) с тем токеном который у нас  вернулся. И соответственно так мы идентифицируем пользователя я правильно Вас понял?

Comment: Ещё не очень понял на счёт обработки своих заголовков - это что именно с ними делать?